# File upload handling with Jersey, Glassfish 4 and Netbeans for non Maven project

Tags: java, netbeans, jersey, glassfish

I'm having trouble in implementing file upload handling with Jersey, Glassfish 4 and Netbeans. I know there are a lot of tutorials out there but all of them use maven projects.

Like we know that in Netbeans web application project, after we choose Glassfish as the server, we can use all of the JEE API cause automatically Netbeans add JEE API from Glassfish to our library (like in the picture below). I think its only for compiling and not included in the deployed war.

[image]

We can even make a new non web Java application and use JEE API by adding Java EE 7 API to our library, its just API for compiling, in the runtime all of the classes are provided by the server (like in the second picture ).

[image]

Now, I want to use the Jersey Multipart API for handling file upload. Glassfish already has the required jars in its modules folder, like jersey-media-multipart. (3rd picture), I know that they are provided in the runtime but I need them to compile my project. Simply adding the jars to the project library is not a proper way cause it gives me a lot of weird errors and we know we shouldn't cause Glassfish already provides them.

[image]

I need something like Jersey Multipart API to compile the project so that in the runtime the project uses all of the classes that Glassfish already provides. Just like the Java EE 7 API Library that Netbeans provides and work well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the solution...

If you only add the jersey-media-multipart, you'll get error HttpReader not found so you need to aadd all of the jersey jars in the glassfish modules.

Next, right click on the libraries folder in the netbeans project and in the compile tab, uncheck all of the jersey jars in the package column to make them get excluded when we build/ run the project .

[image]

Hope this helps anyone who have similar issue.